# research on Encryption for master

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, file-encryption

I'm tring to choose an way for an Encryption mothod for my research?
So,I want to choose one-layer encryption or multilayer encryption,and I want it to be easy to applicable.

when I search about it, I found Homomorphic and linear programing that used for encryption. But still I could not find an way that never used for research topic.

Comment: Hussein, welcome to our site. Unfortunately your question is very broad and unclear. I suggest you look at our help center, especially the [tour](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better feel for the types of questions to ask on this site. If you follow the guidance there, this sit will be much more useful for you.

Comment: Hussein, I appreciate the recent edit, but we cannot come up with your research topic for you.